# How do I to make a sprite move using a timer in java?

Tags: java, timer, sprite

Well, I'm very(meaning just started a few months ago) new to Programming, I'm learning java.

Anyway, How do I make a sprite move using a timer say:

```
  private Timer timer = new Timer(5000,this);
```

and a Sprite like this:

```
    private JLabel player = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("Sprites/apple.png"));
```

With a constructor like this:

```
 public timing()
{
    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(null);
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(1280,720);
    player.setBounds(x,y,100,100); //Use this for moving!
    c.add(player);

    timer.start();
    addKeyListener(
        new KeyAdapter(){

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
                String key = e.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode());
                if(key.equals("Down"))
                {
                  What Do I put Here?
                }}});


}
```

So every second, the sprite

```
  player
```

will move like

```
  x+=5 and y+=5
```

While I am using

```
  public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g);
    player.setBounds(x,y,100,400);
}
```

(I'm very sorry for I'm just a kid learning JAVA)

Comment: You should search this site for `Swing Timer Animation`, that's what you should do. There are several good examples that are easily found.

Comment: Take a look at [Motion Using the Keyboard](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for some examples. The `KeyboardAnimation` is the example that uses a Timer, but you should understand the other first to learn some basics.

Comment: Let me Clarify:

When I press the Down key I want the sprite to move using a timer.

like:
I press the down key
The Sprite moves for 5 Seconds

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you want to do is when you press "down" you want to start a timer.

What you can do is:

```
if(key.equals("Down"))
{
   long start=System.currentTimeMillis();
   while(start%5000==0)
       repaint();
}
```

What repaint() does is call the paint() method.

So:
What you should do is draw your image in the paint() method.
When you call repaint(), you call paint(), so all you need to do is increment x and y by 5  in the paint() method!

Result: Everytime you repaint(), you erase everything in that component and then paint again, but with this x+5 y+5 coordinates, giving the effect of the image moving.

Hope this helps and Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In your paint() method, create an Ellipse2D object and use the fill method to render "player".

To simplify, assume "player" is a circle

```
class DrawSurface extends JComponent{
public void paint(Graphics g){

    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) g;
    x_pos += 5;
    Shape player = new Ellipse2D.Float(x_pos, 0, 30, 30);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fill(player);

}
}
```

In your keyPress method, add the following

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            String key = e.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode());
            if(key.equals("Down")){
            DrawSurface canvas = new DrawSurface();
            ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(3);
            executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(canvas.paint(), 0L, 30L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            }
}
```

scheduleAtFixedRate executes paint() repeatedly in every 30 time units